# How to dynamically auto populate a input field uisng Nodejs and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a field in my website where I want users to enter book names that they can checkout from the database. I want it so that when they start typing the names I want suggestions or drop down under the input box matching the name of the book they are typing.

Is it possible to achieve something like this? I have a books table in my MySQL database and I am using Nodejs as my backend. I have searched a lot online but did not find anything related to this online. Therefore, I decided to ask the question here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send AJAX request with type GET and send the typed character to the Backend.
and in backend you have to do query for ex :`select * from book where name like %input%`
Then you have to return the result as an array to the front-end.
Finally, in your front-end code you have to render the result array under the input.
Also, you can use any ready jquery plugin to do this task in front-end code.

Comment: it is theoretical answer and general thought so it is not solving the problem . if possible then post the code snippet .

Answer (score 0):

The UI element is commonly called a ["typeahead"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_search) or autocomplete.

Twitter release their frontend component as a jQuery plugin called [typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/). Most frontend frameworks will have an equivalent plugin or component.

The backend datasource for the books is up to you to implement.

For small datasets you can render the required book data within the page so it is directly accessible from your javascript.

For large datasets you will probably need to create a backend "book search" service in Nodejs. Typeahead libraries can send that user input to a URL via an AJAX request and the service returns the matching results, usually as a JSON object.

[Code for geek example](https://codeforgeek.com/ajax-search-box-using-node-mysql/) for your stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a drop-down menu with book names and using ajax you can get value from the input and search in database and display data .

I suggest you to use mongo db as database.

You can find  tutorials in w3 schools or
in malayalam https://www.youtube.com/c/Crossroadstalk